# How to pass a command line argument to build.gradle script with -P and use that argument as a dependency package

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a project in which the build.gradle is hard coded with the dependency package ( :config-packages:geocloud-relay-cfg-dev-lxd ) as below

```
plugins {
    id "nebula.ospackage" version "5.2.0"
}

def configname="$configname"

project.evaluationDependsOn ':acds-pkg'
project.evaluationDependsOn ':config-packages:configname'
project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/rpm/${project.name}"
apply plugin: "nebula.ospackage"

buildRpm {
    requires("java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel")
    directory("/opt/geocloud", 0755)
}

task createDataDir(type: Copy) {
    dependsOn project(':config-packages:configname').tasks['configTar']
    from tarTree(resources.gzip(project(':config-packages:configname').buildDir.toString() \
                + "/distributions/configname-${project.version}.tar.gz"))
    into file("${project.buildDir}/data")
}

ospackage {
    packageName 'geocloud-caac'
    version "${project.version}_${getDate()}"
    release '2'
    arch 'X86_64'
    os 'LINUX'
    type 'BINARY'
    summary 'Creating CAAC RPM package'
     from("${project.buildDir}/data") {
        into "/opt/geocloud/"
        fileMode = 755
    }

    postInstall file("postInstallCaac.sh")
}

tasks['createDataDir'].dependsOn project(':config-packages:configname').tasks['configTar']
tasks['buildRpm'].dependsOn tasks['cleanBuildRpm']
tasks['buildRpm'].dependsOn tasks['createDataDir']
tasks['createDataDir'].dependsOn tasks['cleanCreateDataDir']
```

Tried below

./gradlew buildRpm -pconfigname=some-config-name

but didn't work got the issue as below

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':rpm:caac'.
> Project with path ':config-packages:configname' could not be found in project ':rpm:caac'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

My main idea is to parameterize the dependency of the project in the build.gradle , I am looking for the same.